# What species of bird is this?

Tags: birds, bird-watching, india

I have been observing this bird in my surrounding since month. It makes a loud melodious sound. Does someone know which bird species is this?

The location is western India

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your location into the post - it is invaluable to know country or region when identifying animals or birds

Comment: An idea of the size would also be good, perhaps by comparison to more familiar species, or measuring something it perches on. I have an idea though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Asian Koel (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_koel), specifically a female.

[image: Asian Koel photo (female)]

CC-BY-SA 3.0 Wikipedia user [Dougjj](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Dougjj)

It's a member of the cuckoo family, and like other cuckoos it's a brood parasite.  This species is found across much of southern and eastern Asia.

The background of the pictures suggested India to me, confirmed by the OP's profile.  I've only visited India once but I still have my [field guide](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Birds_of_Northern_India.html?id=bRttDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).  The bill shape and long tail suggested I should look around the cuckoos, and there it was.

Comment: +1 I love that this site enables someone from half across the world to answer some bird-identification question in another persons backyard...

Comment: She is beautiful. I don't know what a "brood parasite" is, but it looks like a bird of prey with that sharp beak.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I know, I wish I took that picture.   Brood parasites lay their eggs in the nest of other species (often much smaller birds) so their young are somebody else's problem.  They mainly eat fruit as adults, but also insects and small animals, so that beak is useful